# Renomear novos arquivos sem interferir nos antigos

Tags: linux, script, bash

Preciso renomear alguns arquivos `.srt`, porém se eu fizer da forma atual ele vai impactar nos arquivos antigos.

Eu tenho vários arquivos de legenda que eu já editei para `pt-BR.srt`, porém com a adição de novos arquivos, se eu usar meu script, ele vai renomear os antigos, jogando mais um `pt-BR` na frente e ficando assim duplicado.

O que eu preciso, é que o script identifique o arquivo `.srt` puro, e que renomeie para `pt-BR.srt` sem renomear os antigos.

Abaixo segue o script que utilizo.

```
for f in $(find . -name "*.srt"); do mv "$f" "$(echo $f | sed 's/\.srt/.pt-BR.srt/;')"; done
```

Comment: troque o `mv` por `cp`

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde,

Um jeito simples seria assim

```
find -type f -not -name "*pt-BR.srt" -name "*.srt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema adicionando o comando `grep`. Com isso, consegui o que realmente queria.

Ficou assim:

```
for f in $(find . -name "*.srt" | grep -v "pt-BR"); do mv "$f" "$(echo $f | sed 's/.srt/.pt-BR.srt/;')"; done
```